# OVH Failover IP on Ubuntu 19

Tags: server, 19.04, ip, router, failover

OVH Failover IP

I have one one failover IP from OVH and i am trying to assign the ip to Ubuntu 19 vm I am using vmware Esxi i did all correct configuration but when i try to ping 8.8.8.8 its say "Ping Connect Network is unreachable".

I have tried to assing Static ip  and also tried to use this [Ubuntu 18.04 SERVER VPS on failover IP OVH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062406/ubuntu-18-04-server-vps-on-failover-ip-ovh)
 But its create yml error

please help me on this

Thanks

Comment: is your gateway and static routes ok, seems that your packets are not going anywhere on your system.

Comment: Actually it was YML script issue. Not it resolved posting working code now


network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
          ens160:
                  dhcp4: no
                  dhcp6: no
                  addresses: [x.x.x.x/32]
                  gateway4: 54.36.166.254
                  nameservers:
                          addresses: [208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220]
          routes:
          - to: x.x.gwaddress/32
            via: 0.0.0.0
            scope: link